# Rails Ambiguous Where Clause Error in scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
default_scope {where("valid = ? AND active = ? AND mrp > ?", false, true, 0)}
```

I am getting  Column 'mrp' in where clause is ambiguous error

how do I make it less ambiguous. I tried it with product.mrp

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
default_scope {where("your_table_name.valid = ? AND your_table_name.active = ? AND your_table_name.mrp > ?", false, true, 0)}

Comment: You saved my life about using joins because i didn't understand what means *Ambiguous Where*.